Faster way to calculate compound function of trigonometric and inverse trigonometric function.
We know that $\arcsin(\sin x) = x$ holds true only for $x \in [-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}]$ for if $x$ does not lie in that interval, we need to add or subtract some multiple of $\pi$, or even need to change its sign. All that can be concluded from the graph of this function, and so goes for other trigo-inverse-trigo pairs.
For example: $\arcsin(\sin5) = 5 - 2\pi$
However, is there any faster way to calculate these values without the need to draw the graph every time? A method more time-efficient?

Why don't you learn the graph? It's very straightforward, only the alternate shifting of the lines $y=x$ and $y=-x$...and this way is very fast

Sure, I know the graph, but I'm asking this for a competition exam, where every second matters. And in questions where all three trigo-inverse-trigo pairs are involved with their argument as an integer (non-multiple of pi, it takes longer time to plot all three graphs and locate all those integers between those multiples of pi.

I think I know about that competitive exam. Also, can you give an example where all three trigo-inverse-trigo pairs are involved? It will help people to give an easier and better method.

@MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad let's say: $\arcsin(5) + \arccos(6) + \arctan(7)$

Calculate each individually....this can be done under 1 min....note that $5$ lies between $3\pi/2$ and $2\pi$....$6$ lies between $\pi$ and $2\pi$..... and $7$ lies between $2\pi$ and $5\pi/2$
